# Celery flower's Broker tab is blank

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm running celery and celery flower with redis as a broker. Everything boots up correctly, the worker can find jobs from redis, and the celery worker completes the jobs successfully.

The issue I'm having is the Broker tab in the celery flower web UI doesn't show any of the information from Redis. I know the Redis url is correct, because it's the same URL that celeryd is using. I also know that the celery queue has information in it, because I can manually confirm that via redis-cli.

I'm wondering if celery flower is trying to monitor a different queue in the Broker tab? I don't see any settings in the flower documentation to override or confirm. I'm happy to provide additional information upon request, but I'm not certain what is relevant.

Answer (score 18):

Turns out I needed to start Celery Flower with both the `broker` and `broker_api` command line arguments:

```
celery flower --broker=redis://localhost:6379/0 --broker_api=redis://localhost:6379/0
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: what if you are using aqmp? I am already defining it in teh `--broker` option. do i need to input the exact same for the `--broker_api` option?

Comment: This has to be a new requirement. I have another website where I do not have to pass broker_api wtih redis.  And their docs seem to give the impression this is AMQP only: http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=broker_api#broker-api

Answer (score 5):

For AMQP this is an example.

`/usr/bin/celery -A app_name --broker=amqp://user:pw@host//vhost --broker_api=http://user:pw@host:host_port/api flower`

The broker_api is the rabbitmq web ui endpoint with /api

Comment: `--broker_api=http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/` worked for me for the version 3.6.9-1.

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628492) might be useful for those using a Docker network and/or Airflow

Answer (score 1):

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

that was help me from http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=broker_api#broker-api

Comment: OP are using Redis, not Rabbit

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue with RabbitMQ. Here is how I have it works:

```yaml
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management

  flower:
    image: mher/flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    command:
      - "celery"
      - "--broker=amqp://guest@rabbitmq:5672//"
      - "flower"
      - "--broker_api=http://guest:guest@rabbitmq:15672/api//"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Brokers & other tabs will show up.