# Celery Flower Broker Tab not populating with broker_api set for rabbitmq api

Tags: celery, flower

I'm trying to populate the Broker tab on Celery Flower but when I pass a broker_api like the following example:

```
python manage.py celery flower --broker_api=http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/
```

I get the following error:

```
state.py:108  (run) Failed to inspect the broker: 'list' object is not callable
```

I'm confident the credentials I'm using are correct and the RabbitMQ Management Plugin is enabled.  I'm able to access the RabbitMQ monitoring page through the browser.

- flower==0.6.0
- RabbitMQ 3.2.1

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you open a bug report in https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/new and include the stack trace with debug logging (with --debug option)?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash after /api/:

`python manage.py celery flower --broker_api=http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on an Airflow setup with Celery 5.2.6 and Flower 1.0.0. The solution for me was to launch Flower using:

```
airflow celery flower --broker-api=http://guest:guest@rabbitmq:15672/api/
```

For non-Airflow readers, I believe the command should be:

```
celery flower --broker=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672 --broker_api=http://guest:guest@rabbitmq:15672/api/
```

A few remarks:

- The above assumes a shared Docker network. If that's not the case, every `@rabbitmq` should be replaced with e.g. `@localhost`
- `--broker` is not needed if running under Airflow's umbrella (it's passed from the Airflow config)
- A good test to verify the API works is to access http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/index.html locally